Why didn't Feyd-Rautha react when Paul killed the Baron in front of him?
Paul Atreides ended Baron Vladimir Harkonnen's life with a single, fatal stab
to the neck, right before the eyes of Feyd-Rautha, the Baron's nephew and
protege.
Why didn't Feyd-Rautha react when Paul killed the Baron in front of him?

Note: In the book (and the Lynch film, miniseries), it was Alia, Paul's sister that finished-off the Baron long before Paul arrived in the Emperor's presence..

@JiminyCricket. - Feyd and Rabban were "inspecting the perimeter" when the Baron died, and would have been unaware until they arrived at the Emperor's ship, shortly before Paul did.

He did react as Paul Muad Dib walk back past him: he smiled with something akin to lust, presumably because his cousin actually just did something that Feyd only suggested he would himself do in a fit of pique after fighting the un-drugged Atredies soldier in the arena.

At the moment that Paul killed the Baron, Feyd had no particular reason to react - he was concerned about what would happen next, not what just happened.
Feyd-Rautha is a hardened killer, who has personally killed many fighting slaves in the ring, face-to-face. Blood and death will not shock him. Furthermore, his relationship with the Baron is complicated - Feyd-Rautha is the heir, but he and the Baron are using each other and Feyd-Rautha attempted to assassinate the Baron himself. A dead Baron was just fine with Feyd-Rautha - and he's confident enough to think that he can kill Paul with ease, so he has no reason to see death in the offing for him.

Yep. He tried to finish off the Baron himself at least once (poison needle in the thigh of a pretty slave).
